# Javascript- get multiple data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi I am using the following script to load data in my dashboard. I am using 4 different files to get 4 different integers. Is there a way to do it in single file?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
    $('#1').load('record_count1.php').fadein(slow); // file1
    }, 1000); // refresh every n milliseconds

    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
    $('#2').load('record_count2.php').fadein(slow); //file2
    }, 2000); // refresh every n milliseconds

    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
    $('#3').load('record_count3.php').fadein(slow); //file3
    }, 3000); // refresh every n milliseconds

    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
    $('#4').load('record_count4.php').fadein(slow);  //file4
    }, 4000); // refresh every n milliseconds
    </script>


    <div id="1" align="center"  class="users2"> //result1

    </div>
    <div id="2" align="center"  class="users2"> //result2

    </div>
    <div id="3" align="center"  class="users2"> //result3

    </div>
    <div id="4" align="center"  class="users2"> //result4

    </div>
```

Comment: Have the script return an array using `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `record_count.php?num=1` and then using functions or write a switch statement in the one php file?

Then make a JavaScript function:

```
function reloadRecordCount(num) {
setInterval(function() {
    $('#'+num).load('record_count.php?num='+num).fadeIn("slow"); //file2
    }, (num * 1000));
}
reloadRecordCount(1);
reloadRecordCount(2); // etc...
```

e.g.
record_count.php

```
<?php

switch($_GET['num']) {
    case 1:
        return 'data for 1';
    break;
    case 2:
        return 'data for 2';
    break;
    case 3:
        return 'data for 3';
    break;
    case 4:
        return 'data for 4';
    break;
default:
        return 'nothing';
break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine. But i would like to learn one more thing.... whether the reloads happen every second simultaneously

Comment: @Indra: Do you want them to happen simultaneously so that they all update at once or one after the other a second apart like in your example code? If you want to return it all in one go, you'll need something different. Let me know and I'll update the code.

Comment: I want to load one after the other

Comment: Ok, well with that script, it will load one after the other most of the time. It runs .load every second for 1, every 2 seconds for 2, every 3 seconds for 3 and every 4 seconds for 4. So by the time record 4 has been updated, it will have updated record 1, 4 times, and record 2 twice. Even if record 2 is requested after record 1, it could be returned first if the network/script is slower as well.

Perhaps you could just run the script every second and return as a `json_encode(array())` array, then use JS to display 1, wait a second, 2, wait a sec, 3, wait a sec, then 4? then start again?

Comment: Thanks for your effort.Can you share the sample code for json array